# Use user input and configfile to write to a new file

Tags: python-2.7, list, input, counter, user-input

I am pretty new to coding, and I am attempting to have a user input words (zones). I want these to be put into a list that can be used to pull from based on the counter. The rest of the input is being pulled from a file and then then broken up using shlex.split. I'm then naming these linetokens and using them for my if statements and my naming. I was wondering if someone could look at the following code and let me know what I'm doing wrong. I don't receive any errors when I run it; however, nothing happens. I'm using python 2.7. *After adding the "main(sys.argv[1])", the script now runs but I am still receiving errors.

```
import sys
import shlex

def inputZone(zone):
    zones = raw_input('Enter zones: ')
    return zone

def main(argv):
    count = int(0)
    zones = zone.split(' ')
    sys.stdout.flush
    argv = sys.argv
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        configfile = open(str(sys.argv(1),'r'))
    for configline in configfile:
        with open('converted.txt','a') as converted:
            linetokens = shlex.split(configline)
        while count <= len(zones):
            if(linetokens[0]=='set' and linetokens[1]=='group' and linetokens[3]==zones[count] and linetokens[5]=='add'):
                groupObject=linetokens[4].replace(' ','_').replace('[','').replace(']','').strip()
                groupZone=linetokens[3].strip(' ')
                addressObjectName=linetokens[6].replace(' ','').replace('[','').replace(']','')
                converted.write("set security zones security-zone " + groupZone + " address-book address-set " + groupObject + " address " +  + addressObjectName +'\n')
                count = count + 1

configfile.close()
main(sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

whats the error you are getting. I can notice many python errors in the program.

`main(argv)` argv is never used

`zones = zone.split(' ')` Zone is not declared by this time.

`sys.stdout.flush` is a function definition, you are not really calling it

Comment: I actually stop using the user input as I couldn't get it to work.